# slurm AllocMem always 0

Tags: memory, job-scheduler

When running jobs with `--mem` or `--mem-per-cpu` the `AllocMem` stays 0 when the job is running.

```
# scontrol -V
slurm 2.6.5
# sbatch --mem=2500 tmp.sh 
Submitted batch job 25
# squeue 
             JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
                25      main   tmp.sh     root  R       0:05      1 w1
# scontrol -o show node w1 | awk '{ print $1, $13, $14}'
NodeName=w1 RealMemory=3764 AllocMem=0
```

Why is that the case?

I would expect there to be a number corresponding to my `mem` requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify that you want to use Memory as a Consumable Resource.
Check in the Slurm config file that you have `SelectTypeParameters=CR_CPU_Memory` or something stating Memory and that the select plugin that you are using is the `SelectType=select/cons_res`.